# C++ Overloading issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is the first time I've tried overloading in c++ (Still learning, of course) and I'm not quite sure why this code is erroring?

```
bool operator<= (Vector3 v) {
    if (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The errors are

19|error: expected identifier before '(' token|

and

19|error: expected ';' before '(' token|

I searched for both of these and found that the first one is for code outside of a function (which it's not), but didn't find anything on the second.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, it worked after adding them. Also thanks for showing me the shortcut, like I said I'm new to coding and C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic of the operator aside, you seem to be missing a set of parentheses in the `if`. This would by syntactically correct:

```
if ( (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z) )
```

But what you really should do is simplify the whole thing and avoid the unnecessary `if`:

```
bool operator<= (Vector3 v) {
    return (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z);
}
```

Finally, a comparison member function should be `const`, because it does not make sense to modify something while comparing it. Also, you may want to pass the argument by reference, although that depends on the size of `Vector` and on the cost to copy it.

```
bool operator<= (const Vector3& v) const
{
    return (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

also adding to other answers, what would your statement return if not true, c++ doesn't return anything by default, that is why is better to return the operation result

```
return (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

The  condition in the if statement shall be enclosed in parentheses. So the valid if statement will look as

```
if ( (x <= v.x) && (y <= v.y) && (z <= v.z) ) {
```

Also it would be better to defined the operator the following way

```
bool operator <=( const Vector3 &v ) const 
{
    return ( ( x <= v.x ) && ( y <= v.y ) && ( z <= v.z ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: You might consider this:

```
inline bool operator<= (const3 Vector& u, const Vector3& v) {
    if(u.x < v.x) return true;
    if(u.x == v.x) {
       if(u.y < v.y) return true;
       if(u.y == v.y) {
          if(u.z <= v.z) return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here you have a freestanding binary function, which takes the arguments by  constant references to avoid needless copies. Also the logic is changed (x has a higher rank than y and y a higher rank than z). This makes [1, 1, 1] less than [1, 1, 2] (which is not the case in your logic).